# Waitfor More than 24 hours for execution in MS SQL server R2

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-agent-job

**MY PROBLEM(scenario):**

There is a already a built in method call **"WAITFOR"** that can make the execution of a for example a **"Stored Procedure"**. This waiting can only be done for less than 24 hours.

But the thing is my client who is also a developer wants to find a method to go around this issue and find a way to wait more than 24 hours to reduce the **development time**.

There is already a method. That can query necessary tables once a day and send the necessary emails to the customers ect..

I know that since this **"WAITFOR"** is limited to 24 hours, There has to be a performance issue as this number of **"WAITFOR"** executions go higher (For example 2000).

**MY QUESTION:**

1. Is there a way of holding a stored procedure more than 24 hours. Lets say for more than 14 days.
2. If there is not a method to work this out,,How should I defend on this issue, What are the facts that I can give to my client, Such as Performance Issues,,

This is what I think,,
Since this waiting is limited to 24 hours is that there is no other option to give the expected functionality to perform a data base task precisely on time. But this gives a big over head to the server to keep the track of each **"WAITFOR"** execution. If this is more than 2000 or so,, This is impossible to bear for the server.

The best option available is to have a **"SQL Agent Job"** that run once a day(as you wish) and get the values that are related to set the **WAITFOR** to execute some job precisely on time.

Please give me a much better understanding on this issue of waiting for more than 24 hours. To go for the next alternative. :((((

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you explain why you want to make a stored-procedure take more than 14 days to execute? I'm pretty sure there are better ways to implement what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: waiting for such a long time sounds like a big design problem to me. I would really advice you to use a job and maybe re-engineer your logic. We don't exactly know whats going on so maybe there is an argument i can't think of. More detail?

Comment: @RB.This is for sending mails to the customers on time( customer joined us on 14th at 12.34h so to send a email 18th at 12.38h ,, add 4days and 4 minutes) :)

Comment: Yep - that's a job for SQL Server Agent, or a Windows Service, or similar. Alex K's answer is completely correct. You really do not want to abuse **WAITFOR** to implement this functionality.

Comment: @Diode - as an example of the issues with this design, consider that using using it would mean that you could not restart the SQL Server without killing all the waiting SPIDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way of holding a stored procedure more than 24 hours. Lets
>   say for more than 14 days.

Yes, 14 x 24 hour `WAITFOR`'s for example .. but of course that would be **terrible beyond all ability to describe**; you are forcing a connection to remain open for that period, consuming resources on the server for that period and so on.

What you describe is *precisely* what an SQL Agent Job is for, use one.

Answer (score 1):

The question about WAITFOR limitation could be solved in easy way- just do "Waitfor" couple of times:

```
Declare @i int;
Set @i = 0;
While @i < 5
Begin
    Set @i = @i + 1
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
End;
```

If you want to execute some job after a precise time period other alternative could be use service broker (SB) and dialog timer. (i just love SB, so maybe i see the usage for it everywhere..).

In SB you can send message (witch may include time when it should run or you can just put fixed time) and start dialog timer. that way you will not keep connection open.

SB [BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx), and [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx).